# Edge shows blank page with '#' symbol on reload

Tags: c#, asp.net, microsoft-edge

On Live Server page, using c#.net, on filling the form and clicking save, it saves and reloads the page. 
On Edge on reload, shows blank page containing only '#' symbol. 
Not able to reproduce the issue on my local machine, making it harder to find the issue.
This issue does not occur on any other browser, not even on IE.
I have the doctype declared `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">`

**This is the console log before the page reloads:**

> HTML1300: Navigation occurred. BookingDetails.aspx (1,1)
>
> HTML1524: Invalid HTML5 DOCTYPE. Consider using the interoperable
>   form “!DOCTYPE html>”. BookingDetails.aspx (3,1)
>
> HTML1114: Codepage utf-8 from (HTTP header) overrides conflicting
>   codepage iso-8859-1 from (META tag) BookingDetails.aspx (1,1)

**This is the console log when the page goes blank:**

> HTML1300: Navigation occurred. BookingDetails.aspx (1,1)
>
> HTML1405: Invalid character: U+0000 NULL. Null characters should not
>   be used. BookingDetails.aspx (1,2)
>
> HTML1527: DOCTYPE expected. Consider adding a valid HTML5 doctype:
>   “!DOCTYPE html>”. BookingDetails.aspx (1,2)
>
> HTML1507: Unexpected character: U+0000 NULL. Null characters should
>   not be used. BookingDetails.aspx (1,2)

**Edit:**
The issue seems to be happening with a asp:HiddenField and html input fields.
When the value contains a style and round brackets (only happen with the open round bracket)
The text with which i was able to reproduce the issue was 
**"(**

"

Comment: Show relevant code.

Comment: What code are you executing after the save, to redisplay this page?

Comment: The code spans over multiple interlinked pages, so not really sure what should i share here. All it does is go through each custom field in the form and checks and validates the fields.

Comment: I am getting the same symptoms if the page contains an anchor with a mailto href tag. Edge seems to be converting what it sees as telephone numbers to clickable links on the same page. Perhaps that is what is causing this bug.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider changing to `xhtml5` and then validating at [validator.w3.org](http://validator.w3.org). Make sure you don't add anything after `</html>` tag. Not even a new line. Also make sure you don't have two or more adjacent hyphens inside comments.